# render same page with javascript in mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc4. I am using partial view. In that partial view, I need fill original and negative images. On the first time, I am loading original images and when I press the toggle button, I need to update the partial view with negative images without going to the controller.

**Note:** I got both original and negative image from controller.

Please help me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you load both original and negative images, I guess that the negative ones are in an invisible div. So you just have to toggle the visibility of both your original image and of your negative one.

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="image-1"><img src="..."></div>
<div id="image-neg-1" class="invisible"><img src="..."></div>
<button id="toggle-1" />
```

**Javascript code:**

```
document.getElementById("toggle-1").onclick = toggleImage;

function toggleImage() {
    var firstImage = document.getElementById("image-1"),
        vis = firstImage.style.display;

    document.getElementById("image-1").style.display = (vis === "none") ? "block" : "none";   
    document.getElementById("image-neg-1").style.display = (vis === "none") ? "none" : "block";
}
```